# Finding the limit of a composite function

Tags: limits

Given this limit, which method is correct?

Method 1:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \cos\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\right)$ = $\cos\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\right)\right)$ = $\cos\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left(x+1\right)\right)$ = $\cos(2)$

Method 2: 
$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \cos\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\right)$ = $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \cos\left(x+1\right)$ = $\cos(2)$

For the second method, I didn't think that it was possible to manipulate inside the parenthesis of cosine, so I'm a little confused about it. I thought that the first method is correct because it is a composite function and cosine is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Both are correct

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that $\cos(x)$ is continuous for all real $x$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0}\cos(f(x)) = \cos(\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x))$